# Vuetify using one search / combo box to achieve multiple filtering like Gmail

Tags: vue.js, datatables, vuetify.js

Hi basically I would like to create functionality similar to Gmail search. So for example I will have a set list of columns that user can filter by i.e. id, name etc. So the way Gmail search works is that it give hits for example from:, subject:, date-begin: etc. which I believe can be achieved using autocomplete or combo box with vuetify. However I am struggling to use user input value as value for selected item which I then need to send to backend to fetch the results.

```
<v-combobox
   :items="autoCompleteItems"
   hide-selected
   label="Search/Filter.."
   :allow-overflow="false"
   multiple
   dense
   clearable
   :auto-select-first="true"
   item-text="text"
   item-value="value"
   @update:search-input="fetch"
 >
     <template v-slot:selection="{ attrs, item, parent, selected }">
         <v-chip
            v-if="item === Object(item)"
            v-bind="attrs"
            :input-value="selected"
             label
             small
             class="mt-3 mb-3"
         >
            <span class="pr-2">
                {{ item.text }} {{ item.value }}
            </span>
            v-icon
               small
               @click="parent.selectItem(item)"
            >
               $delete
           </v-icon>
        </v-chip>
     </template>
 </v-combobox>



 autoCompleteItems: [
    {text: 'id:', value: 'id'},
    {text: 'name:', value: 'name'},
    {text: 'location:', value: 'location.name'},
 ]
```

So with the code above when user selects an item from available options the value will be whatever is in the value property of the selected option which is correct and expected behavior. However I would like it use user entered value like in Gmail app instead of a set value. For example, name: Paul, location: England. Is it possible to achieve this? Any help will be much appreciated.

Please see link to what I have so far:
https://codepen.io/harshpatel01/pen/xxdGydj

Comment: you have `@update:search-input`. it does exactly what you want - emits the user input.

Comment: @IgorMoraru yes that is what I am trying to work with right now however looks like there will be a lot of messy code as I need to allow user to select multiple filter and user cannot select another option until the value has been entered for previously selected filter. So just wondering what will be the cleanest and most practical way to achieve what I require.

Comment: This is unclear: `I would like it use user entered value like in Gmail app instead of a set value`. And so is your example. Can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: @tony19 I have added link codepen project. Basically I would like to allow user to select filter from the dropdown and then enter value for it. So essentially I am trying to allow users to filter by multiple values by using one search text / combo box instead of having a text box for each data table header that user can filter by if that makes sense.

Comment: That unfortunately was unhelpful, as the problem is still unclear. Please update the question with example data, and the expected behavior.